# Custom FIlter that matches two fields

Tags: symfony, doctrine, api-platform.com

I simply want an API endpoint that matches two fields, `registrationId` and `hash`.

I cannot find any examples of this online, I can only single matches, regex matching, OR clauses etc.  Nowhere is there an example of just just querying the database to return a row that matches two columns.

I have a table called `registrationhashes`.  In the entity I have added this line:

`#[ApiFilter(RegistrationSearchFilter::class, properties: ['registrationId', 'hash'])]`

And then I have gotten so far with writing a custom filter:

```
final class RegistrationSearchFilter extends AbstractFilter
{

    protected function filterProperty(string $property, $value, QueryBuilder $queryBuilder, QueryNameGeneratorInterface $queryNameGenerator, string $resourceClass, Operation $operation = null, array $context = []): void
    {
        if ($property !== 'search') {
            return;
        }

        $alias = $queryBuilder->getRootAliases()[0];
        $queryBuilder->andWhere(sprintf('%s.registrationId = :search AND %s.hash = :hash', $alias, $alias));
    }

    public function getDescription(string $resourceClass): array
    {
        if (!$this->properties) {
            return [];
        }

        $description = [];
        foreach ($this->properties as $property => $strategy) {
            $description["regexp_$property"] = [
                'property' => $property,
                'type' => Type::BUILTIN_TYPE_STRING,
                'required' => false,
                'description' => 'Filter using a regex. This will appear in the OpenApi documentation!',
                'openapi' => [
                    'example' => 'Custom example that will be in the documentation and be the default value of the sandbox',
                    'allowReserved' => false,// if true, query parameters will be not percent-encoded
                    'allowEmptyValue' => true,
                    'explode' => false, // to be true, the type must be Type::BUILTIN_TYPE_ARRAY, ?product=blue,green will be ?product=blue&product=green
                ],
            ];
        }

        return $description;
    }
}
```

I have just put the description function in there copied from somewhere else for now.

But as you can see from the WHERE clause I ned to match registrationId AND hash, but I only have one value to match with.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Look at the [search filter docs](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/filters/#search-filter), you will see an example of combining two search filters. I believe this accomplishes your task without the need for a custom filter.

```php
use ApiPlatform\Doctrine\Orm\Filter\SearchFilter;

#[ApiResource]
#[ApiFilter(SearchFilter::class, properties: ['registrationId' => 'exact', 'hash' => 'exact'])]
class RegistrationHash
{
    // ...
}
```

The endpoint would then be something like:
`http://localhost:8000/api/registrationhashes?registrationId=10&hash=3C76B43F`

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  Its nice that I dont have to use a custom filter, but I cannot get the SearchFilter to work.  I put the two params into Postman and query the resource, but It returns a collection of all entries, because all endpoints are open it is just doing a GetCollection.